# Scala - Abstract message handlers with Generic parameters

Tags: scala, generics, aws-lambda

I'm using Scala with AWS lambdas, handling different types of events. Each 'Handler' class is a different lambda handler and will only be used for one type of message, but to share common handling code, I'm pulling stuff up into abstract classes + traits

When the time comes to hand off processing specific to each message type to the subclass, I end up with an abstract method and I still need to do a pattern match on the type of the message, always logging some sort of error if the wrong type of message makes it into the handler subtype.

These default cases seem redundant as the wrong type of message will never get to the wrong handler subtypes.

This is a simplified version of what I've got

```
trait Message {
    val text: String
}

case class MessageA(text: String, errorCode: Int) extends Message
case class MessageB(text: String, url: String) extends Message

abstract class MessageHandler {
  protected def processMessage(message: Message)

  ...
}

//Lambda handler 1
class MessageAHandler extends MessageHandler {

  override protected def processMessage(message: Message) = message match {
    case a: MessageA => handleErrorCode(a.errorCode)
    case _ => //log some error - This should never be reached
  }

  ...
}

//Lambda handler 2
class MessageBHandler extends MessageHandler {
  override protected def processMessage(message: Message) = message match {
    case b: MessageB => handleUrl(b.url)
    case _ => //log some error - This should never be reached
  }

  ...  
}
```

I've tried to implement the `processMessage` call with Type bounds, but this doesn't seem to make much difference, I still need to pattern match on 'M' to determine the Subtype of the message parameter, so it can be treated as such.

`protected def processMessage[M <: Message](message: M)`

Has anyone had to do anything similar and is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the Message type abstract in the base type:

```
abstract class MessageHandler {
  type Msg <: Message
  protected def processMessage(message: Msg)
}

class MessageAHandler extends MessageHandler {
  type Msg = MessageA
  protected def processMessage(message: MessageA) = 
    handleErrorCode(message.errorCode)
}
```

But I'm not sure whether this will then be easy to handle from the call-site (the code calling `processMessage`). Potentially the pattern match just moves there (but would probably still be more elegant overall).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I was looking at  Abstract Types but hadn't actually tried it yet. I managed to do it without the pattern matching moving up in to the call-site by pulling the calling code down into the sub classes. It still  ends up cleaner and more elegant than before.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of inheritance here. Put the code to handle the message inside of your trait, and let polymorphism do the work for you.

```
trait Message {
  val text: String
  def handleMessage
}

case class MessageA(text: String, errorCode: Int) extends Message
{
  override def handleMessage = handleErrorCode(errorCode)
}

case class MessageB(text: String, url: String) extends Message
{
  override def handleMessage = handleUrl(url)
}

case object MessageHandler 
{
  def processMessage(message: Message) = message.handleMessage
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, and normally I would take it, however, the message case classes are used for JSON deserialisation (circe) and I'd prefer to keep handler code out of them. That said, I have partially used your suggestion so thank you